# Tags for the games "Village" and "Villages"

Tags: discussion, status-completed

There are two games released in 2011, one called [Village](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/104006/village) by eggertspiele and another called [Villages](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/114684/villages) by The Game Crafter, LLC. I recently created [villages](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/villages) for a question about the latter without incident.

However, we have an untagged question for the former: [In Village (2011) are the winning strategies really balanced?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8569/in-village-2011-are-the-winning-strategies-really-balanced) Unfortunately, the site won't let me create [village](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/village) for it because it is too close to [villages](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/villages), which now exists.

Would it be possible for someone with the proper privileges to create this tag? Or are there better tag names we should have for the two of them?

Comment: Sounds like this is needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's done. It appears this required mod privileges.